# Is there a confirm dialog with preview button upon delete in RCP Application?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am creating a delete-object confirm dialog. e.g."Are you sure you want to delete this item?". My items are in a tree view, therefore they could have many children and grandchildren.

I was wondering if there is any thing similar to when we try to delete e.g. a package in Eclipse projects package explorer, where a "preview" button is around and could display additional info before confirming a delete.

I appreciate any hint and/or help!

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would have to create your own confirm dialog.

You could start with a `JFace` [TitleAreaDialog](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/TitleAreaDialog.html).

You would display the tree view or a part of the tree view in the body of the dialog.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I though that could be something easier before I dive deep into creating that dialog.